# Is there any way to prove stability for a discrete state space model by using Singular Value Decomposition?

Tags: control-theory, svd, optimal-control, stability-theory, linear-control

Assume that we have this state model representation

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k)$$

To check stability of this model, we need to check the eigenvalues. In discrete mode,  $\lambda$ will result both a real part and an imaginary part. 
$$det(\lambda I - A) = 0$$

If the 
$$1 > \sqrt{\lambda_{real} ^2 + \lambda_{img}^2}$$

Then the system is stable. But is it possible to prove that by using Singular Value Decomposition?

$$A = USV^T$$

Where $S$ contains the singular values (real positive) in a diagonal order, where the largest is at the top and the smallest is on the bottom.

I wonder this because

$$det(\lambda I - AA^T) = 0$$

Is equivalent to
$$A = USV^T$$
$$S \equiv \sqrt \lambda$$

Let's say that I compute the eigenvalues $\lambda$ from

$$det(\lambda I - AA^T) = 0$$

Can I then determine if $A$ is stable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Since $\rho(A) \leq \lVert A \rVert_2 = \sigma_\max(A)$ you can immediately deduce stability if $\sigma_\max(A)<1$, where $\sigma_\max$ is the maximum singular value. However, converse is not true and this is a very conservative way for checking stability.  Most likely you will get $\sigma_\max(A) > 1$ even if the system is stable, unless $A$ is in a special form.

Comment: Well, in this case, $AA^T$ will always become symetric with real numbers. So all I need to to to check if the system is stable is the first signular value of $S$ ? I don't care what value it will be, as long I can prove it's stable.

Comment: Assuming the singular values are ordered decreasingly, yes. If the first singular value is less than 1, you can say that the system is stable.

Comment: Yes. All SVD algorithms will sort the largest sigular value first.

Comment: In this case, $A$ is not symetric, but  $AA^T$ is symetric. I'm planning to find the singular values from $AA^T$ to determine if $A$ is stable.

Comment: Did you understand the part that if $\lambda_\max(AA^T)>1$, then you can say nothing about the stability of the system, right?

Comment: Yes I understand that. But what algorithm should I use if the $A$ is not symetric? Most of the SVD-algorithms are made for specific shapes e.g symatric or hessian. Not, randomly.

Comment: Just check the spectral radius of $A$. It is an *if and only if* condition. So, you can always say something about stability.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try that!

Comment: I tried spectral radius, and the solution was power iteration method. But that won't work for a matrix that is $A^T = -A$, e.g skew-symmetric matrix.